# tymon/jwt-auth package show error in laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel

I install a new project of Laravel 5.8 but when I install JWT Auth package,

```
composer require tymon/jwt-auth
```

it shows an error saying

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for tymon/jwt-auth ^0.5.12 -> satisfiable by tymon/jwt-auth[0.5.12].
    - Conclusion: remove nesbot/carbon 2.17.0
    - Conclusion: don't install nesbot/carbon 2.17.0
    - tymon/jwt-auth 0.5.12 requires nesbot/carbon ~1.0 -> satisfiable by nesbot/carbon[1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.1.0, 1.10.0, 1.11.0, 1.12.0, 1.13.0, 1.14.0, 1.15.0, 1.16.0, 1.17.0, 1.18.0, 1.19.0, 1.2.0, 1.20.0, 1.21.0, 1.22.0, 1.22.1, 1.23.0, 1.24.0, 1.24.1, 1.24.2, 1.25.0, 1.26.0, 1.26.1, 1.26.2, 1.26.3, 1.26.4, 1.27.0, 1.28.0, 1.29.0, 1.29.1, 1.29.2, 1.3.0, 1.30.0, 1.31.0, 1.31.1, 1.32.0, 1.33.0, 1.34.0, 1.34.1, 1.34.2, 1.34.3, 1.34.4, 1.35.0, 1.35.1, 1.36.0, 1.36.1, 1.36.2, 1.4.0, 1.5.0, 1.6.0, 1.7.0, 1.8.0, 1.9.0].
    - Can only install one of: nesbot/carbon[1.26.3, 2.17.0].
    - Can only install one of: nesbot/carbon[1.26.4, 2.17.0].
    - Can only install one of: nesbot/carbon[1.27.0, 2.17.0].
    - Can only install one of: nesbot/carbon[1.28.0, 2.17.0].
    - Can only install one of: nesbot/carbon[1.29.0, 2.17.0].
    - Can only install one of: nesbot/carbon[1.29.1, 2.17.0].
    - Can only install one of: nesbot/carbon[1.29.2, 2.17.0].
    - Can only install one of: nesbot/carbon[1.30.0, 2.17.0].
    - Can only install one of: nesbot/carbon[1.31.0, 2.17.0].
    - Can only install one of: nesbot/carbon[1.31.1, 2.17.0].
    - Can only install one of: nesbot/carbon[1.32.0, 2.17.0].
    - Can only install one of: nesbot/carbon[1.33.0, 2.17.0].
    - Can only install one of: nesbot/carbon[1.34.0, 2.17.0].
    - Can only install one of: nesbot/carbon[1.34.1, 2.17.0].
    - Can only install one of: nesbot/carbon[1.34.2, 2.17.0].
    - Can only install one of: nesbot/carbon[1.34.3, 2.17.0].
    - Can only install one of: nesbot/carbon[1.34.4, 2.17.0].
    - Can only install one of: nesbot/carbon[1.35.0, 2.17.0].
    - Can only install one of: nesbot/carbon[1.35.1, 2.17.0].
    - Can only install one of: nesbot/carbon[1.36.0, 2.17.0].
    - Can only install one of: nesbot/carbon[1.36.1, 2.17.0].
    - Can only install one of: nesbot/carbon[1.36.2, 2.17.0].
    - Can only install one of: nesbot/carbon[1.0.0, 2.17.0].
    - Can only install one of: nesbot/carbon[1.8.0, 2.17.0].
    - Can only install one of: nesbot/carbon[1.9.0, 2.17.0].
    - Installation request for nesbot/carbon (locked at 2.17.0) -> satisfiable by nesbot/carbon[2.17.0].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

I tried everything but nothing seems to work for me.
Then, I check this link 
https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/issues/1764

how to resolve this?

Comment: Have you tried to install older version of package?

Comment: Check [these](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/issues/1795) solutions.

Comment: it is not support to  laravel 5.8 version. use old version like 5.7 version

Answer (score 10):

In order to install JWTAuth in Laravel 5.8 you need to use following

```
composer require tymon/jwt-auth:dev-develop
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there's an [open issue](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/issues/1795#issuecomment-506195963) on github. 
Solution: `composer require tymon/jwt-auth:1.0.0-rc.4.1`

To install and properly use this with Laravel 5.8, you need `"tymon/jwt-auth": "1.0.0-rc.4.1"`. NOT `0.5.x` and NOT even `1.0.x`.

I use it and everything just fine.

Answer (score 3):

This package does not support PHP 8.0 yet

You can add      `composer require tymon/jwt-auth --ignore-platform-reqs`

`--ignore-platform-reqs` works for me, also you need the latest composer.

Answer (score 1):

The package you are trying to install requires carbon 1.x but you are locking carbon at version 2.x. You neeed to downgrade carbon to 1.x, Laravel currently does not require carbon 2 so maybe you required it explicitely on your composer file, or by requiring another package that needs carbon 2.x.
If you could post your `composer.json` file we could look up what package is requiring carbon 2.x.

Answer (score 1):

As of today, `tymon/jwt-auth` is still in pre-release. Check out and install [the latest release](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/releases), for example:

```
composer require tymon/jwt-auth:1.0.0-rc.5
```

Answer (score 0):

Composer requires: `tymon/jwt-auth:^1.0.2 --ignore-platform-reqs`

Comment: This is same as @king-neo answer.